# Remove ^H and ^M characters from a file using Linux shell scripting

Tags: linux, shell

How do I remove ^H and ^M characters from a file using Linux shell scripting?

```
^[[0^H ^H^H ^H^H ^H^H ^H^H ^H^H ^H^H ^H^H ^H   rcv-packets: 0
^[[0^H ^H^H ^H^H ^H^H ^H^H ^H^H ^H^H ^H^H ^H      rcv-errs: 0
     rcv-drop: 0
     rcv-fifo: 0
     rcv-frame: 0
```

Comment: Note: If `^H` were generated by `html2text`, use `-nobs` option to avoid them.

Answer (score 25):

What you're seeing there are control characters, you simply could delete them with `tr`

```
cat your_file |
tr -d '\b\r'
```

this is better:

```
tr -d '\b\r' < your_file
```

Comment: @dtmilano: yes, sorry, edited that - I learned cat in university and still use it even though some shells I work on have the 'useless use of cat detected' warning

Answer (score 9):

Two methods come to mind immediately:

- `tr -d control+v control+h`
- `sed 's/control+v control+h//g'`

Here's both in action:

```
$ od -c test
0000000  \b   h   e   l   l   o  \b   t   h   e   r   e  \b  \n
0000016
$ sed 's/^H//g' < test | od -c
0000000   h   e   l   l   o   t   h   e   r   e  \n
0000013
$ tr -d ^H < test | od -c
0000000   h   e   l   l   o   t   h   e   r   e  \n
0000013
```

Comment: +1 for the sed solution and doing the formatting for the keyboard entries (though mine looks better)

Answer (score 2):

For removing ^M characters appearing at the end of every line, I usually do this in vi editor.

```
:%s/.$//g
```

It just removes the last character of every line irrespective of what the character is.
This solved my provlem.

Comment: Nice trick! Right what I was looking for. I found on some site to use :%s/^M//g , but it didn't work. Can you tell me why?

Comment: '^' indicates start of the string/word/line... So, your expression might mean all the words/lines that starts with 'M' should be replaced or deleted... Alternatively, you can also use this: `:%s/\/r//g` to remove those characters.

Comment: "irrespective of what the character is" is not usually what you want; the comment "`:%s/^M//g` didn't work" is probably because the "^M" was typed literally; it actually meant "control-M", which can be "typed" by doing `control-V` + `control-M`. Even better (as per others answers) is just `tr -d '\r'`, or `unix2dos {file}`.

Comment: @michael_n: I think you mean `dos2unix` for deleting the carriage returns. `unix2dos` would add them.

Answer (score 0):

Use `sed` utility.
See below as per [examples](http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-scripting/34704-removing-character-using-sed.html):

```
sed 's/%//' file > newfile
echo "82%%%" | sed 's/%*$//'
echo "68%" | sed "s/%$//" #assume % is always at the end.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove all control characters by using `tr`, e.g.

```
tr -d "[:cntrl:]" file.txt
```

To exclude some of them (like line endings), check: [Removing control characters from a file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36561728/55075).

Answer (score 0):

if you want to change original file, do this:

```
sed -i '.bak' 's/^M//g ; s/^H//g' test.md
```

(^M is `control+v` `control+m`)
(^H is `control+v` `control+h`)

much file, you can do this:

```
find source -name '*.md' | xargs sed -i '.bak' 's/^M//g ; s/^H//g'
```

Answer (score 0):

I used dos2unix and it worked for me.

If you are using a Debian-based distro, you should be able to do `sudo apt-get install dos2unix`.

If you are using a RH-like distro, you should be able to do `sudo yum install dos2unix`.

Once it is installed, you can just give the target file as an argument

```
dos2unix file.sh
```