# Removing Control Characters from a File

Tags: linux

I want to delete all the control characters from my file using linux bash commands.

There are some control characters like EOF (0x1A) especially which are causing the problem when I load my file in another software. I want to delete this.

Here is what I have tried so far:

this will list all the control characters:

```
cat -v -e -t file.txt | head -n 10

^A+^X$
^A1^X$
^D ^_$
^E-^D$
^E-^S$
^E1^V$
^F%^_$
^F-^D$
^F.^_$
^F/^_$
^F4EZ$
^G%$
```

This will list all the control characters using grep:

```
$ cat file.txt | head -n 10 | grep '[[:cntrl:]]'
+
1

-
-
1
%
-
.
/
```

matches the above output of cat command.

Now, I ran the following command to show all lines not containing control characters but it is still showing the same output as above (lines with control characters)

```
$ cat file.txt | head -n 10 | grep '[^[:cntrl:]]'
+
1

-
-
1
%
-
.
/
```

here is the output in hex format:

```
$ cat file.txt | head -n 10 | grep '[[:cntrl:]]' | od -t x2
0000000 2b01 0a18 3101 0a18 2004 0a1f 2d05 0a04
0000020 2d05 0a13 3105 0a16 2506 0a1f 2d06 0a04
0000040 2e06 0a1f 2f06 0a1f
0000050
```

as you can see, the hex values, 0x01, 0x18 are control characters.

I tried using the tr command to delete the control characters but got an error:

```
$ cat file.txt | tr -d "\r\n" "[:cntrl:]" >> test.txt
tr: extra operand `[:cntrl:]'
Only one string may be given when deleting without squeezing repeats.
Try `tr --help' for more information.
```

If I delete all control characters, I will end up deleting the newline and carriage return as well which is used as the newline characters on windows. How do I delete all the control characters keeping only the ones required like "\r\n"?

Thanks.

Comment: `grep` would grep lines of output unless you are using the `-o` option.

Answer (score 35):

Instead of using the predefined `[:cntrl:]` set, which as you observed includes `\n` and `\r`, just list (in octal) the control characters you want to get rid of:

```
$ tr -d '\000-\011\013\014\016-\037' < file.txt > newfile.txt
```

Comment: Note that this removes the tab character `\t`. Use `tr -d '\000-\010\013\014\016-\037' < file.txt > newfile.txt` to change that

Answer (score 15):

Based on [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/15866) on unix.stackexchange, this should do the trick:

```
$ cat scriptfile.raw | col -b > scriptfile.clean
```

Comment: With thanks to Bruce Ediger https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15855/how-to-dump-a-man-page/15866#15866?newreg=4613fa4638aa4965ac10b183c10678df

Comment: This also seems to add tabs

Comment: if tabs are being added, see `man col` => `-x, --spaces` output multiple spaces instead of tabs

Answer (score 13):

Try `grep`, like:

```
grep -o "[[:print:][:space:]]*" in.txt > out.txt
```

which will print only alphanumeric characters including punctuation characters and space characters such as tab, newline, vertical tab, form feed, carriage return, and space.

To be less restrictive, and remove only [control characters](http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/html_node/Character-Classes-and-Bracket-Expressions.html) (`[:cntrl:]`), delete them by:

```
tr -d "[:cntrl:]"
```

If you want to keep `\n` (which is part of `[:cntrl:]`), then replace it temporarily to something else, e.g.

```
cat file.txt | tr '\r\n' '\275\276' | tr -d "[:cntrl:]" | tr "\275\276" "\r\n"
```

Comment: Note that using grep will add a newline to the end of the file even if that wasn't there before.

Comment: Why '\r\n'? Isn't enough '\n'?

Comment: @AdrianMaire I believe it's for maximum compatibility across all OSes.

Comment: Also try `tr` with complement on: `tr -d -c '[[:print:][:space:]]'`. As an aside, I recommend using `printf '%q' "$x"`, `${(q)x}`, etc. (escaped views) or `hd <<<"$x"` / `printf '%s' "$x" | hd` (hex views per `hexdump`) rather than trying to examine and compare strings with `\r`, etc. (I immediately confused myself testing this.)

Comment: This turns characters like ½ into newlines.

Answer (score 6):

A little late to the party: `cat -v <file>`
which I think is the easiest to remember of the lot!